# Kendo grid with nested collection , complex object

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have some difficulties to make a grid with an editor pop , which has inside a collection.
I found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659920/kendo-grid-with-nested-collection-complex-object) that 's almost like I want, but the grid
 nested , has a GridEditMode.InCell , and I need to GridEditMode.PopUp .

When I try to change CellEditing PopEditing get the following error:
"The Insert data binding setting is required by the insert command . Please specify the Insert action or url in the DataBinding configuration. "

I want the whole object is recorded when the parent object is recorded.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<EmployeeViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Command(comm =>
{
comm.Edit();
});
columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeeID);
columns.Bound(e => e.FirstName);
columns.Bound(e => e.LastName);
columns.Bound(e => e.Title);        
columns.Bound(e => e.HireDate).Format("{0:d}");
columns.Bound(e => e.Territories)
.ClientTemplate("#=territoriesTemplate(Territories)#");       
})
.Editable(ed=>ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
.Pageable()  
.Events(ev=>ev.Edit("onEdit")) 
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.PageSize(5)        
.Model(model =>
{
model.Id(e => e.EmployeeID);
model.Field(e => e.EmployeeID).Editable(false);
model.Field(e => e.Territories).DefaultValue(new List<TerritoryViewModel>());
})
.Events(ev=>ev.Change("onDsChange"))
.Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home"))
.Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Home").Data("serialize")))
)
```

This is the nested grid that need to be edited with GridEditMode.PopUp

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TerritoryViewModel>()
.Name("TerritoryGrid")
.Sortable()
.Columns(cols =>
{
cols.Bound(b => b.TerritoryID);
cols.Bound(b => b.TerritoryDescription);
})
 .Editable(ed=>ed.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.AutoBind(false)
.DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax().Model(mo => { 
mo.Id(m => m.TerritoryID);
mo.Field(f => f.TerritoryID).Editable(false);
}))
.ToClientTemplate()
)
```

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you found the following [**demo**](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/grid-popup-editing-navigation-property-collection-with-nested-grid.aspx) and you want to change it to use popup editing for the nested Grid. It is possible to make the Grid use Popup editing, however the nested Grid will perform separate request.

If you want to achieve both Popup editing + batch updates you will have to declare your Grid via JavaScript since it provides you with way more flexibility.
Or you can use the approach covered in **[this](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/external-editing-container-for-batch-editable-grid.aspx)** code library to achieve similar to popup editing + batch updates.

Comment: if I declare the grid via javsacript could achieve what I want?
You would have an example or something where I can read about it?
I´m going to check the link you provided .

Thanks a lot

Comment: I was seeing the code library you pointed to me ([link]http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/external-editing-container-for-batch-editable-grid.aspx) .The question is why I should set manually the value for  EyeColorIndex ? Should not  the dropdownlist bound to EyecColorIndex property  ? In the example, the value for EyeColorIndex is changed in the save method. ( e.model.set("EyeColorIndex", val);)
        e.model.set("EyeColorIndex", val);